# Tensorflow object detection API how to add background class samples?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using tensorflow object detection API. I have two classes of interest. In the first trial, I got reasonable results, but I found it was easy to get false positive of both classes in the pure background images. These background images (i.e., images without any class bbx) have not been included in the training set.

How can I add them into the training set? It seems not work if I simply add samples without bbx.

Comment: Can you say what fails when you add samples without the bounding boxes?

Comment: I have tried two methods. I am not sure which one is correct. First, I explicitly add background images with class label 0 and class name "background".  Second, I added background images with a non-zero class id. For both methods, the loss decreased smoothly at first but finally exploded.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to add negative images to your training dataset to strength the background class (id 0 in the detection API). You can reach this with the VOC Pascal XML annotation format. In your XML file is the height and width of your image without object. Usually you label objects the coordinates and height and width of your object and object name is in the XML file. If you use labelImg you can generate a XML file corresponded to your negative image with the verify button. Also can Roboflow generates XML files with and without objects.